# Generating a JSON snippet with the same key multiple times

Tags: python-2.7

I am iterating over a list to get a bunch of integers, we'll say that array looks like this:

items = [1,2,3,4]

I need to output this such that it looks exactly like this:

```
"entries": [{"item": 1},{"item": 2},{"item": 3},{"item": 4}]
```

This is turning out to be more complicated then I imagined. I tried the dirty route of just putting things together as a string, but the output JSON has escaped quotes that I can't get rid of. Dictionary objects require a unique key. Is there a straightforward way to generate the exact formatting above?

Comment: that's because that's 4 SEPARATE dictionaries each with one key:value pair in it, which is stored in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick sample to produce what you asked for:

```
{"entries": [{"item": i} for i in items]}
```

It is generating a list of dictionaries using a list comprehension.  The list comprehension is a mechanism for generating lists in a simplified manner and they generally have the form `[i for i in items]`.  For more in depth documentation see: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions